# QTcpSocket соединение между приватными сетями

Tags: qt, сеть, qt5, qtcpsocket

Разрабатываю клиент-серверное приложение, в локальной сети работа понятна, теперь надо делать работу через интернет. Основное требование к работе через интернет - максимальное упрощение подключения для юзеров - никакого порт-форвардинга на роутере и прочих хитрых настроек.

Для этого закладывается центральный сервер (давайте для устранения путаницы в терминологии называть его "маршрутизатором"), сидящий на публичном IP, но очень не хочется пропускать трафик от сервера на клиент транзитом через маршрутизатор, объемы трафика у облачных провайдеров ограничены.

Как концептцальное решение видится такая схема - клиент, который хочет получить данные, идет на маршрутизатор, тот отсылает клиенту способ получения доступа к серверу (адрес/порт/что-то-еще), и далее клиент устанавливает прямое соединение с сервером по тому адресу, который выдал маршрутизатор.

Теперь собственно вопрос - как это сделать средствами Qt? Что должен отдать маршрутизатор, чтобы клиент и сервер могли установить прямое соединение без транзита трафика через маршрутизатор, при том, что клиент и сервер оба могут находиться в разных приватных сетях за натом? В какую сторону смотреть?